# How to remove , in the string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my argument appending with , in last argument I have `Class I-V Tuition,Class VI-VIII Tuition,College Level,engg,`

1.how to remove the , from lastword engg.I am appending the value with , here I don't know how to remove the , in last argument and how to separate the argument value .

What I needed is:

```
 if(class I_V){ do some work here }
 if(class VI-VIII)(do some work here)
```

Comment: wht is text in your code!! plz format your code properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` with `g` flag.

```
var mystring = "this,is,a,test"
mystring.replace(/,/g , "newchar");
```

Comment: Thanks not working you idea is correct but  where is the , in the string see my question my string should have , in lastword. I want to remove that only

Comment: Hi thanks lot how to  bring like this form string if(class I_V){ do some work here }
 if(class VI-VIII)(do some work here)

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure: you have a string:

```
var tmpString = "Class I-V Tuition,Class VI-VIII Tuition,College Level,engg,";
```

and you try to remove the last ","?

You can use the Substring method for that:

```
var tmpString = "Class I-V Tuition,Class VI-VIII Tuition,College Level,engg,";
tmpString = tmpString.substring(0, tmpString.length - 2);
```

This strips the last character from the string.

Read more: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Edit:
If you want to loop through what rests, you can use this code:

```
    var tmpString = "Class I-V Tuition,Class VI-VIII Tuition,College Level,engg,";
tmpString = tmpString.substring(0, tmpString.length - 2);
var subStrings = tmpString.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < subStrings.length; i++)
{
    if (subStrings[i] == "class I-V Tuition")
        //Code here.

}
```

Comment: Thanks lot  how to I separate the string from this .now the the string looks like this after removing ,="Class I-V Tuition,Class VI-VIII Tuition,College Level,engg"  what I looking means  I want to implement some condition like this if(Class I-V Tuition){ do validation)} if(Class VI-VIII Tuition){ do validation) form separation shall I need to use str.split.my question how to loop through that